# Query to Return all Working Periods per Employee and Cost Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have data showing employee, cost code and WeekEnd (Sunday). WeekEnd is the last day of working week, from Monday thru Sunday:

```
EmpID   CostCode   WeekEnd
=============================
    1   1          01/02/2022  
    1   1          01/09/2022
    Employee skipped working in week of 1/16/2022 ...
    1   1          01/23/2022
    1   1          01/30/2022
    1   2          02/06/2022 
    1   3          02/13/2022
    1   3          02/20/2022
```

Need to get result like this:

```
EmpID   CostCode   FirstWeekEnd    LastWeekEnd
==============================================
    1   1          01/02/2022      01/09/2022
    1   1          01/23/2022      01/30/2022
    1   2          02/06/2022      02/06/2022
    1   3          02/13/2022      02/20/2022
```

I need to get all periods (start - end) when employee worked per cost code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by calculating a ranking for sequencial weeks.

Then aggregate also on that ranking.

> ```
> SELECT EmpId, CostCode
> , MIN(WeekEnd) AS FirstWeekEnd
> , MAX(WeekEnd) AS LastWeekEnd
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , SUM(Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY WeekEnd) AS Rnk
>   FROM
>   (
>     SELECT *
>     , IIF(7>=DATEDIFF(day, LAG(WeekEnd) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY WeekEnd), WeekEnd),0,1) AS Flag
>     FROM your_table
>   ) q1
> ) q2
> GROUP BY EmpId, CostCode, Rnk
> ORDER BY EmpId, FirstWeekEnd;
> ```

| EmpId | CostCode | FirstWeekEnd | LastWeekEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-09 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-23 | 2022-01-30 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-06 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-02-13 | 2022-02-20 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38bbe0eba822ca87352c0605caa3e171)*